# Binary quadratic form of $p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Show that if $p\neq2,5$ then there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$p=x^2+10y^2\text{ if } \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1$$
$$p=2x^2+5y^2\text{ if } \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=-1$$

**My attempt**

I wish to solve this problem using the ideal class gorup of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-10})$. That is,
$$H(K)=\{1,[Q]\}$$ where $[Q]$ is the class of the ideal $Q=\langle 2, \sqrt{-10}\rangle$. It is easy to show $N(Q)=2$.

Now let $p\neq 2,5$ be a prime such that ,
$$\left(\frac{-10}{p}\right)=1.$$
That implies,
$$\langle p \rangle =P_1P_2$$
where $P_1$, $P_2$ are distinct conjugate prime ideals in $O_K$. We have two possibilities for $[P_1]=1$ or $[P_1]=[Q]$.

In the first case $P_1$ is principal hence $\exists$ $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $P_1=\langle x+y\sqrt{-10}\rangle$ and
$$p=N(P_1)=x^2+10y^2$$

In the second  case, we have that $[P_1Q]=[P_1][Q]=[Q]^2=[Q^2]=1$ hence $P_1Q$ is principal, hence $\exists$ $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $P_1Q=\langle x+y\sqrt{-10}\rangle$. Then
$$2p=N(Q)N(P_1)=x^2+10y^2$$
Thus we have show that if,
$$\left(\frac{-10}{p}\right)=1$$
then $p=x^2+10y^2$ or $2p=x^2+10y^2$.

***I think my work so far is correct, but how do I proceed?***

Answer (score 2):

The statements which are you are trying to prove you can find in the excellent book by *David A.Cox "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$"* on page 36 Corollary 2.27.

Answer (score 1):

So you found two possibilities for $p$. In the case where $2p=x^2+10y^2$, $x$ must be even as $2$ divides $10y^2$ so it must divide $x^2$. So you have $p=2z^2+5y^2$ where $x^2=4z^2$.

Now you can continue like this If $\Big(\frac{2}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{p}{5}\Big)=1$. Assume $p=2z^2+5y^2$. You have $p=2z^2+5y^2\equiv 2z^2 \mod 5$ which means that $p$ is not a square since $2$ is not a square. You have a contradiction. Now apply this to other case $\Big(\frac{2}{p}\Big)=\Big(\frac{p}{5}\Big)=-1$.

Comment: What is the contradiction? $p$ is a prime hence not a square.

Comment: It can be a square in some modulo. you assume $\Big(\frac{p}{5}\Big)=1$ which means $p$ is a square in modulo 5.